# Display only required DDL value in Edit screen in MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

When I use the JS code below in create view in MVC it works perfect. However I've tried to alter it so that when in edit view it should still only display the textbox when "OtherSpecifyFormGroup" is selected from the create screen. Any help would be great!!

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            //this line fires no matter what
            $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").hide();            
            $("#SelectType").change(function () {
                //alert("in function");
                var value = document.getElementById("SelectType").value;
                if (value == "4") {
                    $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").show("highlight", { color: "#7FAAFF" }, 1000);
                }
                else {
                    $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").hide();
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

HTML code

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectType, "Select Type", new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                        @Html.DropDownList("SelectType", String.Empty)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectType)
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="OtherSpecifyFormGroup">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OtherSpecify, new { @class = "control-label col-md-5" })
                    <div class="col-md-4 sbchanged">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OtherSpecify)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OtherSpecify)
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: I think we also need the HTML. A JSFiddle or similar would be great

Comment: Edited my question to include HTML

Comment: Thanks. How is the DDL populated?

Comment: It is populated through my database table, not hardcoded

Comment: Ok, but how do those values get in the HTML? I don't see anything to suggest the DDL is not emply

Comment: The DDL values are provided through my model class and controller

Comment: It seems you're not injecting the model inside the DDL when you do Html.DropDownList()

Comment: For the other values in the DDL I need the textbox to remain hidden if one of those is selected, its just adjusting this code for the edit view to make that happen

Comment: So you have some sort of Ajax that populates the DDL?

Answer (score 0):

Through working around with the the JS code I finally got it working!

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            if (document.getElementById("SelectType").value != "4") {
                $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").hide();
            }
            $("#SelectType").change(function () {
                //alert("in function");
                var value = document.getElementById("SelectType").value;
                if (value != "4") {
                    $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#OtherSpecifyFormGroup").show("highlight", { color: "#7FAAFF" }, 1000);
                }
            });
        })
    </script>
```

By changing the inital if statement I was able to hide any value which wasn't "4", this meant that if a user selects any other value on the create screen and go into edit that "OtherSpecifyFormGroup" is hidden. The show and hide in the second part of the change was swapped around so that if any value other than "4" was selected while in edit view the textbox remained hidden but when "4" was selected then it appeared.